# Complex conjugate and their product

Tags: complex-numbers, solution-verification

I have two complex numbers that are non real, $k$ and $z$. $k$ and $z$ are going to be complex conjugates if and only if the product $(x-k)(x-z)$ is a polynomial with real coefficients.

Here is my answer :

$$k=a+bi\\
z=c+di\\
(x-k)(x-z) = x^2-(k+z)x+kz$$

After that, I'm not sure what to do. I guess that I need to add $k+z$ and multiply $k*z$.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, look at it this way.

Let $ax^2 + bx + c$ be a 2nd degree polynomial with real coefficients and no real roots.  But it does have complex roots.  What are the roots?

Well by the quadratic equation the are
$z = \frac {-b}{2a} + \frac {\sqrt{4ac - b^2}}{2a} = \frac {-b}{2a} + \frac {\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}i$ (as there are no real roots, we know $b^2 > 4ac$) and $k = \frac {-b}{2a} - \frac {\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}i$

Notice $z$ and $k$ are conjugates;  Their real parts are equal and their imaginary parts are negatives of each other.

!!!!SO!!!!

IF $(x - z)(x -k) = ax^2 + by + c$ is a polynomial with only real coeficients and no real solutions, then z and k are conjugate complex numbers.

WE ARE HALF-WAY DONE!

!!!!NOW!!!! let's suppose z and k are conjugates.  In other words, if $z = a + bi$ and $k = a - bi$, !!!THEN!!! z and k are the roots of the polynomial $(x -z)(x -k$.  That polynomial is $(x - z)(x - k) = x^2 - (z + k)x + zk = x^2 - [(a + bi) + (a - bi)]x + (a + bi)(a - bi) = x^2 - 2ax + (a^2 - b^2)$ has coefficients, $1, 2a,$ and $(a^2 - b^2)$.  These coefficients are *all* real numbers.

!!!SO!!!!  IF x and z are conjugates THEN they are roots of a polynomial with real coefficients.

Now we have completed everything.

$z,$ and $k$ are complex roots to a second degree polynomial that has only real coefficients IF AND ONLY IF $z$ and $k$ are conjugates.

Comment: Not working....

Comment: I was able to prove that b=-d and a=c so thisd proves theyre conjugates. Now, because I have if and only if, I must prove the inverse right ?

Answer (score 1):

So, $k+z=(a+c)+(b+d)i$ and $kz = (ac-bd)+(ad+bc)i$.
Both being real is equivalent to $b+d=0$ and $ad+bc=0$, which in turn is equivalent to $b=-d$ and $a=c$, which is equivalent to $k$ and $z$ being complex conjugate.

Answer (score 0):

The requirement is that $a,b,c,d$ are real numbers such that $k,z$ are representing complex numbers. The sum of real numbers is also a real number and a product of real numbers is also a real number (see also: "field axioms").

Take the product (x-k)(x-z) and simplify then you will get the answer.

Comment: This is what I did...

Comment: @Astroman and what happened?

Comment: I got this : x$^2$x2-(k+z)x+kz After that I added k+z and multiplied kz and replaced. But I wasn't sure what to do after....

Comment: What did you get when you added k + z and multiplied kz (in terms of a, b, c, and d)

Comment: Wait i'm going to re do it I threw my paper away. I guess that I must get some constant and this will prove that I have polynomial with real coefficients

Comment: ok, so k+z= (a+c)+(b+d)i kz=(ac-bd)+(ad+bc)i I replaced it in the equation and I'm going to try and see something

Comment: I'm worried you're overthinking it.  I don't want to just give you the answer but k + z = [a+c] + [b + d]i.  So a+c is the "real part" and "b+d" is the "Imaginary part".  As the polynomial has only real coefficients the "imaginary part" must be 0.  So b + d = 0.  Same thing with (ad + bc); ad + bc = 0.  What does that say about a, b, c, and d and how the relate to each other.  In other words solve for a, b, c, and d in terms of each other.

Comment: In conclusion you are going to want to show that k and z are complements.  What does that say about a, b, c, and d and how they relation to each other.  It *should* be the same results as you got when you tried to show that the polynomial had only real coefficients

Comment: I don't understand. Why do you assume that the polynomial as only reals coefficients ? I know that this is what we want to prove, but what makes it be that way ?

Comment: They are two ways of saying the same thing.  Complex conjugates means that their products are real numbers and they are both the same size.  That happens if and only if they both have the same real parts and their imaginary parts of negatives of each other.  For a polynomial (x --z) (x -k) is going to have coeficients that are sums of z + k (if they are conjugates their imaginary parts cancel each other out) and kz which if they are conjugates  is a real number.  If its a real number but they aren't conjugates than they are not the same size and the sums won't cancel out the imaginary parts.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if

$z = \bar k, \tag{1}$

then taking

$k = k_R + ik_I \tag{2}$

we have

$z = k_R - ik_I; \tag{3}$

thus

$k + z = 2k_R \tag{4}$

and

$kz = k_R^2 + k_I^2, \tag{5}$

both real; thus the implication

$z = \bar k \Rightarrow x^2 - (k + z)x + kz \in \Bbb R[x] \tag{6}$

is established.

Going the other way, if

$x^2 - (k + z)x + kz \in \Bbb R[x], \tag{7}$

writing

$z = z_R + iz_I, \tag{8}$

we have

$(k_R + z_R) + i(k_I + z_I) \in \Bbb R, \tag{9}$

whence

$k_I + z_I = 0, \tag{10}$

whence

$z_I = -k_I; \tag{11}$

then

$k_R z_R + k_I^2 + i k_I(z_R - k_R)$
$= (k_R + ik_I)(z_R - ik_I) = kz \in \Bbb R; \tag{12}$

thus

$k_I(z_R - k_R) = 0; \tag{13}$

since

$k_I \ne 0, \tag{14}$

$z_R = k_R \tag{15}$

and we are done; $z = \bar k$.  ***QED.***